# Mock a method with List<int> as parameter and return List<> with Moq

Tags: c#, .net, mocking, moq

In my test, I defined as data a `List<IUser>` with some record in.

I'd like setup a moq for the method GetList, this method receives a `List<int>` as the parameter. This is a list of Ids; I'd like to return the IUser list with these Ids in the `List<IUser>`

I tried this but I don't find the right Returns syntax

```
Mock<IUsers> mockUserRepository = new Mock<IUsers>();
_mockUserRepository.Setup(m => m.GetListAll(It.IsAny<List<int>>())).Returns(????????);
```

I tried something like this :

```
_mockUserRepository.Setup(m => m.GetListAll(It.IsAny<List<int>>())).Returns(u =>_users.Contains(???));
```

Thanks,

```
class User : IUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Firsname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}

interface IUser
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Firsname { get; set; }
    string Lastname { get; set; }
}

interface IAction
{
    List<IUser> GetList(List<int> listId);
}

class Action : IAction
{

    public List<IUser> GetList(List<int> listId)
    {
        //....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this:

```
mock.Setup(users => users.GetListAll(It.IsAny<List<int>>()))
            .Returns<List<int>>(ids =>
                {
                    return _users.Where(user => ids.Contains(user.Id)).ToList();
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have more as one filter parameter you can use this example

```cs
mock.Setup(o => o.GetListAllAsync(It.IsAny<List<int>>(), It.IsAny<string>())
 .ReturnsAsync((int[] ids, string firstname) =>
 {
   return _users
          .Where(user => ids.Contains(user.Id) && user.Firstname.Equals(firstname))
          .ToList();
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

Just return the prepared list:

```
_mockUserRepository.Setup(m => m.GetListAll(It.IsAny<List<int>>())).Returns(_users);
```

Comment: Sorry, I already try this solution but in the result, I get the full list but I don't want the full list

Comment: In this case look at vvs0205's answer.

Comment: @AndreasSchlapsi This post do not answer the OP question. Please consider editing or maybe delete it.